# Text above and below featured image in a page

Tags: css, wordpress

I have the_content and the featured image showing.

I need to have some text (2 lines for example) and then the featured image and then again some more text. How can I achieve this? Tried float left on the image but the text wont go above it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

Read more here... http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt

Comment: the content is what I need. There is something with css wrong, I just can't see it , right now...

Comment: If I got it right you want:  
1.Some text from the_content()
2.The feature image 3.All the text from the_content() ?

Comment: I've solved this by using custom field. It goes like this: Title, custom field text, featured photo and then the_content().

Answer (score 0):

So what you mean is, you want the image surrounded by text?

Float should work, but it won't, in your case.

If we're talking about the same image (the one at the top of your post), that image is not in the same block as the text so a float won't work.

I'm not sure how wordpress works but what I do know is, for a float to work, the image (or any  element with a display: block for that matter) and the text need to be in the same container.

Would be great if we had a jsfiddle though...

Answer (score 0):

If you want the image surrounded by text you should remove the feature image and put it inside the page's (or post's) content (using the editor). Then click on the image and select "align left" in the properties of the image.

Comment: Yes, now I realized that the featured image is the proper way to go. The problem is, that there are hundreds of posts on the site with the featured image only, therefore, to achieve this effect I will put custom field in between the title and the featured image. Thank you all for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by using custom field. It goes like this: Title, custom field text, featured photo and then the_content().